# Extendscript Debugging Arrays

Tags: arrays, debugging, extendscript

My first question so be gentle...

Using Adobe Extendscript Toolkit CS6 3.8.0.12 to make a few scripts. Trying to see contents of an array in the Data Browser, specifically a pathItem in the pathItems array.

Can't seem to find a way to examine the contents of an array.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pathItems in InDesign or in Illustrator?

Comment: Scripts are for illustrator.

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect elements by adding breakpoints to you script, but it seems like you cant see the contents of pathItems in the data browser. You will have to extract them into variables. E.g. like this:

```
var doc = app.documents.add();
var rect = doc.pathItems.rectangle(100,-100,100,100);
var pathItems = doc.pathItems;
```

See this image for some more hints

[image: inspect things]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good technique when the data browser can't keep up. I did notice that you can see the individual path items when they are selected in your active document. In that case the data browser will have them, perhaps as expected, on the selection property as pathitem 0, pathitem 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options I've used.

**Option 1**

Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [ExtendScript Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug). You can create ExtendScript/JSX files to run inside any Adobe product supporting ExtendScript and then set a watcher on the variable to inspect.

[image: VSCode with ExtendScript Debugger]

```
//foo.jsx
var myArray = ['foo', $.fileName, {a:1, b:'two'}];

'add code break here';
```

```
//.vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "extendscript-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Foo Testing",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/foo.jsx",
            // "stopOnEntry": true,
            // "trace": true, //debugging output
            "targetSpecifier": "indesign-14.064",
            "engineName": "main"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Option 2**

Use a Logger that will output an object for inspection to a file. [jasminejsx](https://github.com/theasci/jasminejsx) uses this [Logger](https://github.com/theasci/jasminejsx/blob/master/model/Logger.jsx) to do just that.